# How to set the MinHeight of the Window of a Win10 UWA?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I found that most UWA's minheight were about 300px.

Looks Like this is the default setting.

But not for those MSN series apps. Their minheight are about 500px.
How they did that?

I tried to set the "minheight" attribute of the page, but it cannot stop my mouse pointer. It seems like the "minheight" only limit the page, but not the window, which keep being shorter and shorter untill about 300px.

What do I need to do? Thank you.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/31885979/windows-10-uwp-app-setting-window-size-on-desktop/31888254

Comment: @JustinXL Thank you, although these two questions are different, but your detailed answer in that question also help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call SetPreferredMinSize method, where you set preferred minimum Height and Width size of you window. For example :

ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(468, 320));

You can call it in App.xaml.cs before Window.Current.Activate();